# Slice/split string Series at various positions

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to split [a string Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801079/attributes-information-contained-in-dataframe-column-names/31861473#31861473) at different points depending on the length of certain substrings:

```
In [47]: df = pd.DataFrame(['group9class1', 'group10class2', 'group11class20'], columns=['group_class'])
In [48]: split_locations = df.group_class.str.rfind('class')
In [49]: split_locations
Out[49]: 
0    6
1    7
2    7
dtype: int64
In [50]: df
Out[50]: 
      group_class
0    group9class1
1   group10class2
2  group11class20
```

My output should look like:

```
      group_class    group    class
0    group9class1   group9   class1
1   group10class2  group10   class2
2  group11class20  group11  class20
```

I half-thought this might work:

```
In [56]: df.group_class.str[:split_locations]
Out[56]: 
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
```

How can I slice my strings by the variable locations in `split_locations`?

Comment: This works: `df[['group_class']].apply(lambda x: x.str[:split_locations[x.name]], axis=1)` the `axis=1` and use of double `[]` is required to force it to a `df.apply` and to get access to the row index to index into the split_locations

Comment: If you're open to an alternative to slicing, I'd go for `df.group_class.str.extract(r'(?P<group>group[0-9]+)(?P<class>class[0-9]+)')`

Comment: Learned loads of great stuff from the answers to this question. @Rob: sorry I had to accept just one. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801079/attributes-information-contained-in-dataframe-column-names/31861473#31861473) for some context on why I asked the question in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, by using double `[[]]` you can access the index value of the current element so you can index into the `split_locations` series:

```
In [119]:    
df[['group_class']].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x.str[split_locations[x.name]:][0], x.str[:split_locations[x.name]][0]]), axis=1)
Out[119]:
         0        1
0   class1   group9
1   class2  group10
2  class20  group11
```

Or as @ajcr has suggested you can `extract`:

```
In [106]:

df['group_class'].str.extract(r'(?P<group>group[0-9]+)(?P<class>class[0-9]+)')
Out[106]:
     group    class
0   group9   class1
1  group10   class2
2  group11  class20
```

**EDIT**

Regex explanation:

the regex came from @ajcr (thanks!), this uses [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas.Series.str.extract) to extract groups, the groups become new columns.

So [`?P<group>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059673/named-regular-expression-group-pgroup-nameregexp-what-does-p-stand-for) here identifies an id for a specific group to look for, if this is missing then an int will be returned for the column name.

so the rest should be self-explanatory: `group[0-9]` looks for the string `group` followed by the digits in range `[0-9]` which is what the `[]` indicate, this is equivalent to `group\d` where `\d` means digit.

So it could be re-written as:

```
df['group_class'].str.extract(r'(?P<group>group\d+)(?P<class>class\d+)')
```

Comment: Actually I think the `str.extract` method is better as this produces both columns, see my update

Comment: I know this is not necessarily the best place for it, but any commentary on how you came up with those `regex`s would be welcome.

Comment: Sure, hope it makes more sense, I'm not a regex ninja but this regex is pretty simple here

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059673/named-regular-expression-group-pgroup-nameregexp-what-does-p-stand-for) is a good discussion about `?P` in regex. (This is actually mentioned in the docstring for Series.str.extract!)

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression to split the string

```
 import re

 regex = re.compile("(class)")
 str="group1class23"
 # this will split the group and the class string by adding a space between them, and using a simple split on space.
 split_string = re.sub(regex, " \\1", str).split(" ")
```

This will return the array:

```
 ['group9', 'class23']
```

So to append two new columns to your `DataFrame` you can do:

```
new_cols = [re.sub(regex, " \\1", x).split(" ") for x in df.group_class]
df['group'], df['class'] = zip(*new_cols)
```

Which results in:

```
      group_class    group    class
0    group9class1   group9   class1
1   group10class2  group10   class2
2  group11class20  group11  class20
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind. I've added the code which will actually produce the desired output. Yes, I had fun!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `zip` together with a list comprehension.

```
df['group'], df['class'] = zip(
    *[(string[:n], string[n:]) 
      for string, n in zip(df.group_class, split_locations)])

>>> df
      group_class    group    class
0    group9class1   group9   class1
1   group10class2  group10   class2
2  group11class20  group11  class20
```

Comment: This wins the instantly-clear-what's-going-on contest!

Comment: Zen: 3) Simple is better than complex.  7) Readability counts.

Comment: I love this, but the existence of `Series.str.extract` plus the `?P<group_name>` thing in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31881349/2071807) blew my mind, so I've accepted that one instead. Thanks though!