# grouping and reordering by partial identifiers in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have data from a csv that produces a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
d = {"clf_2007": [20],
    "e_2007": [25],
    "ue_2007": [17],
    "clf_2008": [300],
    "e_2008": [20],
    "ue_2008": [10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

which produces a data frame (forgive me for not knowing how to properly code that into stackoverflow)

```
   clf_2007     clf_2008    e_2007  e_2008  ue_2007    ue_2008
0   20            300         25       20      17         10
```

I want to manipulate that data to produce something that looks like this:

```
        clf     e     ue
2007    20      25    17
2008    300     20    10
```

2007 and 2008 in the original column names represent dates, but they don't need to be datetime now. I need to merge them with another dataframe that has the same "dates" eventually, but I can figure that out later.

Thus far, I've tried groupbys and I've tried them by string indexes (like str[ :8]) and such, and, outside of it not working, I don't even think groupby is the right tool. I've also tried pd.PeriodIndex, but, again, that doesn't seem like the right tool to me.

Is there a standardized way to do something like this? Or is the brute force way (get it into an excel spreadsheet and just move the data around manually), the only way to get what I'm looking for here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas split column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886929/pandas-split-column-name)

Comment: this solved almost 100% of my problem with some slight modifications to the answer provided. There is still one area I am looking to solve, but I'm certain I can fix that. I will provide an update to my question shortly

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be a lot easier if you pre-process your data to have three columns: `key`, `year` and `value`. Something like:

```
rows = []
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    key, year = k.split("_")
    for val in v:
        rows.append({'key': key, 'year': year, 'value': val})
```

Put those rows into a dataframe, call it `dfA`. I'm assuming you might have more than one value for each `(key, year)` pair and you want to aggregate them somehow. I'll assume you do that and end up with a dataframe called `df`, whose columns are still `key`, `year`, and `value`. At that point, you just need to [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index=['year'], columns=['key'])
```

You end up with multi-indexed rows/columns that you'll want to clean up, but I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a column multiindex:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([col.split("_") for col in df])
print(df.columns)
#   clf         e        ue     
#  2007 2008 2007 2008 2007 2008
```

And then stack the table:

```
df = df.stack()
print(df)
#        clf   e  ue
#0 2007   20  25  17
#  2008  300  20  10
```

You can optionally flatten the index, too:

```
df.index = df.index.get_level_values(1)
print(df)
#      clf   e  ue
#2007   20  25  17
#2008  300  20  10
```